# Jitpack builds successfully, but there is no jar file or jar doesn't contain .class files

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, jitpack, maven-jar-plugin

I'm trying to build my Android library with Jitpack, but it doesn't make any jar file, so I can insert `implementation 'com.github.crylent:midilib:fbcf4f6c1e'` into a gradle file in another project and successfully sync it, but can't import any classes from the library and even don't see the library in the External Libraries list.

In build log:

```
✅ Build artifacts:
com.github.crylent:midilib:b848154487

Files: 
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487/build.log
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487/midilib-b848154487-sources.jar
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487/midilib-b848154487.pom
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487/midilib-b848154487.pom.md5
com/github/crylent/midilib/b848154487/midilib-b848154487.pom.sha1
```

[Full Log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/crylent/midilib/fbcf4f6c1e/build.log)

jitpack.yml:

```yaml
before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "cmake;3.22.1"
  - sdk update
  - sdk install java 17.0.1-zulu
  - sdk use java 17.0.1-zulu
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.crylent</groupId>
    <artifactId>midilib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classesDirectory>src</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply true
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21' apply true
    id 'maven-publish' apply true
}

android {
    publishing {
        singleVariant('release') {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                components.getByName('release')

                groupId = 'com.crylent'
                artifactId = 'midilib'
                version = 'v1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace 'com.crylent.midilib'
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++20 -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '25.2.9519653'
}

dependencies {

    api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    api 'com.google.oboe:oboe:1.7.0'

}
```

```yaml
install:
  - mvn install
```

When I add this to jitpack.yml, I get another [Build Log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/crylent/midilib/c6a34ec524/build.log). Jar exists, but I still can't import classes from the library into another project. When I download jar and [decompile it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS5fh.png), I see uncompiled .kt files instead of .class that I expect to see, as they are in other libraries.